# what is the difference between openam and openid SSO implementation?

Tags: liferay, single-sign-on, openid, openam

As far as my understanding goes, OpenID uses accounts made on other websites to sign in to the website, so that user won't have to create multiple username and password.

Does OPENAM not to do the same thing? It uses providers like Facebook google in order to authenticate the user.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

OpenID Connect is a [standard](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html).

OpenAM is a product that amongst many other things, implements the OpenID Connect standard (both as a client/relying party and as a server/provider).
So, yes, you can configure your OpenAM to work with external OpenID Connect providers to establish sessions at OpenAM, but you can just as well configure your OpenAM to perform authentication against a local directory server and act as an OpenID Connect provider (like Facebook/Google/etc).

Answer (score 0):

Above you mention scenario is Single Sign On (SSO). It provide OpenID-Connect with Oauth.
OpenID is a protocol(Standard).

> OpenID Connect is a simple identity layer on top of the OAuth 2.0
>   protocol.

OAuth only provide authorization using an access token. OpenID-Connect is built on top of OAuth2, in order to provide user authentication information.
Not only OpenID Connect whether we can used SAML(Security Assertion Markup Language) for Single Sign On.Name it

> SAML SSO.

OpenAM is a product and below Link you can read OpenAM feature [Wikipedia OpenAM page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenAM) and additionally you can used another open source Identity Server Name [WSO2 Identity Server](http://wso2.com/products/identity-server/) for implement this feature and there are more additional features as well.

Comment: Sorry, your answer is difficult to read. You might want to review it.